# SQL JOIN two table in tricky way

Tags: sql, join, sqlalchemy

Got stuck in writing tricky `SQL` request.
Here two tables I have: `Book` and `Page`. Each `Book` has multiple `Pages` of content.
Following SQL request:

```
SELECT book.id as "book Id",
       book.date as "Date",
       book.description as "Description",
       page.description as "Page Description",
       page.content as "Page Content"
    FROM book JOIN page
        ON book.id = page.book_id
            WHERE book.id=9
```

with relative `SQL-Alchemy` query:

```
query = db.session.query(
    Book.id.label("book Id"),
    Book.date.label("Date"),
    Book.description.label("Description"),
    Page.description.label("Page Description"),
).join(Page, Book.id == Page.book_id)\
    .filter(Book.id == 9)
```

Gives me following:

[image]

But I need following result:

[image]

Can I build such query? As a result I need to get `json` to be sent on endpoint request with list of book objects having list of page objects.

Comment: If you ultimately want to produce nested JSON then you may be better off creating a query that returns a list of ORM objects and then iterate through that list to generate the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

ALthough it is not clear to me from where `book_id in (52, 53)` respective pages have two empty rows, I presume there are records in `page` table with `book_id in (52, 53)` that have `NULL` values in the description field.
Regardless of that, this query should help:

```
SELECT 
    book_id
  , Date
  , Description
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
          b.id AS book_Id
        , b.date AS Date
        , COALESCE(b.description, '') AS Description
        , 1 as order_col
    FROM book as b

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
          NULL AS book_Id
        , NULL AS Date
        , p.description AS Description
        , b.id as order_col
    FROM book AS b
    INNER JOIN page AS p ON b.id = p.book_id
    ) AS X
ORDER BY coalesce(book_id, order_col) ASC, order_col ASC
```

so, first, you take the book related row from `book` table, then union it with the information of the respective page from `page` table where you treat `book` table fields as `NULL`-s.
The tricky part was the order here, given logic will certainly work in this case, however, you might need to adjust it depending on the data.